# How does baking work and when should you use it?

Tags: texture-baking, retopology

Here's where I'm at: I'm retopologizing a character. The mint green indicates the parts I've retopologized. I didn't model these shoes myself because I think that'd be a little too advanced for me. I downloaded them and originally they consisted of separate parts, but I joined them all together because my plan was to just retopologize over the whole shoe and maybe bake the textures from the shoes I downloaded onto my model. The problem is, I don't have any experience with baking. I've just heard from some videos I've watched that you can sculpt a model, retopologize it, turn the sculpted model's surface into a texture and bake it onto your model.

I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what parts of my plan would work and what wouldn't, and if anyone has any better ideas I'd love to hear them. I'm looking for a way for my characters to have shoes and make them compatible for animation. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: It's a very general question because there are different types of baking and they are used for different purposes. But if you are only interested in texture baking to create apparent details, I recommend starting with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw) but carefully read the comments about how to update the steps for 2.9.

Comment: I checked out that tutorial. I think it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Don't forget that it's for an older version so you need to make some adjustments for 2.9+